# How can I make a bar chart? Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, bar-chart

in my App I'm using CoreData to save and summarize Integers. Now I want to present these Integers in a simple but handsome looking bar chart. It has to show the highest count per the day it was saved into the entity.

Do someone have a simple example of Code I can use? Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KristijanK said [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) is one of the popular frameworks you can link and use. If you're unsure where to start, follow the [demos](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Swift/Demos) provided in the repo as a scaffolding and go from there. Observe how a chart gets instantiated and the data set is being fed.

For example, if you want to use a pie chart to show the proportion of the highest count per day among the entities, `import Charts` first, instantiate the chart `@IBOutlet var chartView: PieChartView!`, and input your data `let set = PieChartDataSet(entries: entries, label: "Entry Count")`.

One notable thing to pay attention to are the [formatters](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Swift/Formatters).  You will most likely want to customize the units of the x-axis or the y-axis depending on what type of charts and graphs you use according to the type of your data set.  For example, a chart showing data per 1000 km is going to be different from data per 1 litre. Use the formatter classes to create a custom method to convert the unit to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

What I have mostly been using is Charts (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts).It is free for use under Apache-2.0 License and offers great customizability. You can view their source code for something more specific and also there are great project examples there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this file for simple drawing no need to import extra library such as Charts. Try and play with below code you will learn new things. Happy coding.

```
extension CGFloat {
    func radians() -> CGFloat {
        let b = CGFloat(M_PI) * (self/180)
        return b
    }
}

extension UIBezierPath {
    convenience init(circleSegmentCenter center:CGPoint, radius:CGFloat, startAngle:CGFloat, endAngle:CGFloat)
    {
        self.init()
        self.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(center.x, center.y))
        self.addArcWithCenter(center, radius:radius, startAngle:startAngle.radians(), endAngle: endAngle.radians(), clockwise:true)
        self.closePath()
    }
}



func pieChart(pieces:[(UIBezierPath, UIColor)], viewRect:CGRect) -> UIView {
    var layers = [CAShapeLayer]()
    for p in pieces {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = p.0.CGPath
        layer.fillColor = p.1.CGColor
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        layers.append(layer)
    }
    let view = UIView(frame: viewRect)
    for l in layers {
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(l)
        
        
    }
    return view
}

let rectSize = CGRectMake(0,0,400,400)
let centrePointOfChart = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rectSize),CGRectGetMidY(rectSize))
let radius:CGFloat = 100
let piePieces = [(UIBezierPath(circleSegmentCenter: centrePointOfChart, radius: radius, startAngle: 250, endAngle: 360),UIColor.brownColor()), (UIBezierPath(circleSegmentCenter: centrePointOfChart, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 200),UIColor.orangeColor()), (UIBezierPath(circleSegmentCenter: centrePointOfChart, radius: radius, startAngle: 200, endAngle: 250),UIColor.lightGrayColor())]
pieChart(piePieces, viewRect: CGRectMake(0,0,400,400))
```